# Oxidation numbers of phosphorus pentachloride

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, molecules, oxidation-state

I read detailed explanations of what oxidation numbers/ states represent and it boils down simply to this: If it's positive, it shows how many electrons the element lost, and in the case of a negative oxidation number, it shows how many electrons the element gained. That I understand.

What I don't get is, in Phosphorus pentachloride $\ce{PCl5}$, phosphorus forms 5 single bonds with chlorine atoms and 'gains' $5$ more electrons to accommodate a total of $10$ electrons. Shouldn't its oxidation number be $-5$ instead of $+5$?

Answer (score 3):

When considering the oxidation state of covalent compounds, we need to pretend they are ionic. When we do so, we [assign all of the electrons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxidation_state#Using_electronegativity) to the **more electronegative** element. The electronegativity of phosphorous using [the Pauling Scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronegativity#Pauling_electronegativity) is 2.19 and the electronegativity of chlorine is 3.16. Since chlorine is the more electronegative element, we assign all electrons in the bonds to the chlorine atoms. Thus $\ce{PCl5}$ is treated as the fictitious ionic compound comprised of $\ce{P^{5+}}$ ions and $\ce{Cl-}$ ions.